# Create New Rows based on valid to and valid from dates

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that has account number, end of month valid from and end of month valid to columns.
What I need is a table that has account number and a column that has all the end of month dates of when the account was live, inclusive of end of month valid to. [The Current Table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QdmM.png)

[New table will need to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7W6g.png)

I have tried using a calendar table and an CTE table type query but have had no success.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].
Please read the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) and [edit] your question accordingly.
Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using ***Using multiple comma separated CTEs in a statement***

**Query**

```
with t0 (i) AS (select 0 union all select 0 union all select 0 union all select 0 union all select 0 union all select 0),
     t1 (i) AS (select 0 from t0 a inner join t0 b on a.i = b.i), 
     n (i) AS (select row_number()over(order by i)  from t1),
     Account_details (Account_number,valid_from,valid_to,mth,Live_date)As(

     select  Account_number,valid_from,valid_to,   datediff(month,valid_from,valid_to ) mth, valid_from"Live_date" 
     from tbl1
     union all
     select  Account_number,valid_from,valid_to,   datediff(month,valid_from,valid_to ) mth, EOMONTH (dateadd(month,n.i,valid_from)) "Live_date" 
     from tbl1
     inner join n on 1=1 and n.i between 1 and datediff(month,valid_from,valid_to ) 
     )
select * 
from Account_details
where Account_details.Account_number =1
order by  Account_details.Account_number
```

**Output**

[image]

CTE Table t0, t1 and n will generate numbers. This is a best way to generate rows without any data.

Then the CTE table Account_details is used to pull data from the table.

Comment: please accept answer by clicking the green check sign and upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on sql on the msdn thread [how to get month end date between two dates.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6fafa175-abc7-407a-90f7-01d7b3a75d53/how-to-get-month-end-date-between-two-dates?forum=transactsql)

```
DECLARE @Old AS Table (AccountNumber INT, ValidFrom DATE, ValidTo DATE)
DECLARE @New AS Table  (AccountNumber INT, LiveDate DATE)

INSERT INTO @old
SELECT 1, '20130630', '20131130' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '20130630', '20131231' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '20120430', '20120531' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '20170331', '20171130'

SELECT TOP 100 * FROM @old

DECLARE @AccountNumber INT, @ValidFrom DATE, @ValidTo DATE
DECLARE @Cursor CURSOR

SET @Cursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT AccountNumber, ValidFrom, ValidTo
    FROM @old

    OPEN @Cursor

    FETCH NEXT INTO @Cursor FROM @AccountNumber, @ValidFrom, @ValidTo

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
    BEGIN        
            ;WITH cteEndMonthDates (MonthEndDate)
            AS
            (
                   SELECT eomonth(@ValidFrom) AS MonthEndDate
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT eomonth( dateadd(day, 1, MonthEndDate)) AS MonthEndDate
                   FROM   cteEndMonthDates
                   WHERE  MonthEndDate  < eomonth(@ValidTo)
            )
            INSERT INTO @new (AccountNumber, LiveDate)
            SELECT @AccountNumber, MonthEndDate
            FROM cteEndMonthDates

        FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @AccountNumber, @ValidFrom, @ValidTo    
    END

    CLOSE @Cursor    
    DEALLOCATE @Cursor

SELECT * FROM @New
```

Edit: Or without the cursor

```
DECLARE @Old AS Table (AccountNumber INT, ValidFrom DATE, ValidTo DATE)
DECLARE @New AS Table  (AccountNumber INT, LiveDate DATE)

INSERT INTO @old
SELECT 1, '20130630', '20131130' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '20130630', '20131231' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '20120430', '20120531' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '20170331', '20171130' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, '20180430', '20190131'  UNION ALL
SELECT 6, '20160430', '20180531' 

SELECT TOP 100 * FROM @old

    ;WITH cteEndMonthDates (AccountNumber, MonthEndDate)
    AS
    (
            SELECT AccountNumber, eomonth(ValidFrom) AS MonthEndDate
            FROM @Old
            UNION ALL
            SELECT x.AccountNumber, eomonth( dateadd(day, 1, MonthEndDate)) AS MonthEndDate
            FROM   cteEndMonthDates x
            JOIN @Old o ON o.AccountNumber = x.AccountNumber
            WHERE  MonthEndDate  < eomonth(ValidTo)
    )
    SELECT AccountNumber, MonthEndDate
    FROM cteEndMonthDates
    order by AccountNumber, MonthEndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
    ;WITH Span AS (

        SELECT 
            AccountNumber,
            ValidFrom AS Valid

        FROM dbo.Input
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            AccountNumber,
            DATEADD(DAY, 1, Span.Valid) AS Valid
        FROM Span
            WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, Span.Valid) <= (SELECT ValidTo FROM dbo.Input WHERE AccountNumber = Span.AccountNumber)
    )
    SELECT * FROM Span
    ORDER BY Span.AccountNumber, Span.Valid
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```